# City_id in the where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have wrote the query , but it is showing city id in the  where clause is ambigious

```
SELECT
  `a`.`name`,
  `a`.`company`,
  `a`.`city`,
  `a`.`country`,
  `a`.`phone`,
  `a`.`type_of_enquiry`,
  `b`.`enquiry_id`,
  `a`.`hearaboutus`,
  `a`.`email`,
  `a`.`comments`,
  `a`.`address`,
  `c`.`id`,
  `c`.`city_id`
FROM (`sobha_enquiry` a)
  LEFT JOIN `sobha_enquiryzone` b
    ON `b`.`enquiry_id` = `a`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `sobha_admin` c
    ON `c`.`city_id` = `b`.`city_id`
WHERE `city_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `id` desc, `a`.`id` DESC
```

Pls help me !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `a`.`name`,
  `a`.`company`,
  `a`.`city`,
  `a`.`country`,
  `a`.`phone`,
  `a`.`type_of_enquiry`,
  `b`.`enquiry_id`,
  `a`.`hearaboutus`,
  `a`.`email`,
  `a`.`comments`,
  `a`.`address`,
  `c`.`id`,
  `c`.`city_id`
FROM (`sobha_enquiry` a)
  LEFT JOIN `sobha_enquiryzone` b
    ON `b`.`enquiry_id` = `a`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `sobha_admin` c
    ON `c`.`city_id` = `b`.`city_id`
WHERE `a`.`city_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `c`.`id` desc, `a`.`id` DESC
```

In you where clause you should provide either b or c because are using aliases and the columns city_id exists in both table which is confusing mysql

Comment: maybe you mean `b or c` not `a or c`.

Answer (score 2):

the problem lies in the `WHERE` clause, you need to specify what table will be search for `city_id` sice both of them contains the same column name. It could be either from `sobha_enquiryzone` or from `sobha_admin`.

```
SELECT  a.NAME,
        a.company,
        a.city,
        a.country,
        a.phone,
        a.type_of_enquiry,
        b.enquiry_id,
        a.hearaboutus,
        a.email,
        a.comments,
        a.address,
        c.id,
        c.city_id
FROM    sobha_enquiry a
        LEFT JOIN sobha_enquiryzone b
                ON b.enquiry_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN sobha_admin c
                ON c.city_id = b.city_id
WHERE   b.city_id = '2' -- or c.city_id = '2' (both will yield the same result)
GROUP   BY a.id
ORDER   BY id DESC, a.id DESC
```